# How do you prove the sum of the roots of a complex polynomial is a ratio of two coefficients?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to follow Proof 1 from here:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Roots_of_Polynomial.

It proves that a complex polynomial

$p(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0 $ with complex roots $z_1,...,z_n$ has the property $z_1+z_2+...z_n=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$

I understand the proof uses the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) to re-write $p(z)$ in factored form.  It then multiplies out each of the factors.

After multiplying out all the factors, you get something that looks like:

$p(z)=z^n+z^{n-1}(z_1+z_2+...z_n)+z^{n-2}(z_1z_2+z_1z_3+..+z_1z_n+z_2z_3+z_2z_4+...z_2z_n+...) + ... + z(z_1z_2z_3...z_n)+(-1)^nz_1z_2z_3...z_n$

All this makes sense to me so far.

However, I am lost at the point in Proof 1 when it says

> Equating powers of z, it follows that:
>
> $-a_n(z_1+z_2+...z_n)=a_{n-1}$

What happened to the rest of the coefficients of $z^{n-2},z^{n-3},z^{n-4},.. $ and so on? Also, what does "equating powers of z" mean?

Comment: Two polynomials are equal if and only if they have the equal coefficients.

Comment: It might be better to say "equating coefficients"

Comment: I think that the $(-1)^1$ is missing in your expression for $p(x)$. You have factorized a polynomial with a highest coeffizient of $1$. Now, multiply it with $a_n$ and have a look at the resulting second highest coefficient...

Comment: @zhw or "equating coefficients at corresponding powers of $z $".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to divide the polynomial you have by $a_n$.

Then the coefficient of $z^n$ becomes $1$ and you have a "standard form" which is called a "monic polynomial" - the coefficient of the highest power is $1$.

[This is important in two aspects - first because it makes a standard for comparability of polynomials over fields (where division, except by zero is possible); and over rings - where division is not always possible monic polynomials are used to define generalised integers. It proves to be a powerful idea and is worth understanding.]

Then there is a theorem which says that if two monic polynomials of degree $n$ agree on $n$ values (here the roots with multiplicity) then the polynomials are equal.  The difference of the polynomials has degree $n-1$ and if it is not zero it has a most $n-1$ roots rather than $n$ points of equality. If the polynomials are equal, then their coefficients are equal.

So it is putting some basic pieces together.